# CoffeeScript compiler errors suppressed under Node 0.5.10-pre

Tags: coffeescript

When my script fails to parse for any reason, I get a stack trace from the compiler, with no insight at all into where in my script the problem lies:

```
mpurvis@citadel:~/coffee$ coffee -c Test.coffee

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/command.js:15
    return process.binding('stdio').writeError(line + '\n');
                   ^
Error: No such module
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/command.js:15:20
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/command.js:167:7
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/command.js:115:26
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (fs.js:108:5)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:64:17)
    at afterRead (fs.js:1074:12)
    at Object.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:246:17)
```

For now, it's just a toy script to try the system out, so I can usually just experiment until it works again, but that would be impossible in a file of any size. Is there some trick I'm not seeing to get the line where the error occurred?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what Test.coffee looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't look like a syntax issue. The error is coming from `command.js`, which is what defines the `coffee` command-line utility. If it were a compiler error, it would be from `coffee-script.js`.

So why is the `process.binding('stdio')` bit in `command.js` failing? There are two possibilities I can think of:

1. You're using a weird shell (or a weirdly configured one) that doesn't play nice with Node's version of stdio. This seems unlikely, but it's possible...
2. You're using a version of Node.js that CoffeeScript isn't currently compatible with. What do you get when you do `node -v`? Your safest bet is the latest 0.4.x, since those are stable releases (0.5.x is experimental).

Comment: Ah, I see, this is probably it. I'm on v0.5.10-pre; most of the instructions I found for setting it up centered around checking out the git repo. Is there a better way?

Comment: Okay, I ran `git checkout v0.4.12` in my checkout dir, and then rebuilt, and it seems to be much better now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

the latest version from node isn't full compatible with cs..the node_stdio module ws removed...a simple way for fix it is open /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/command.js and change the line 15

process.binding('stdio').writeError(line + '\n')

for

process.stderr.write(line + '\n')

always you can get more help from github issues section
https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/commit/c77f7737a5d94a05a999109810ea7634f540e1e2

good luck and happy coding

Answer (score 1):

This question is from awhile back.

Node 0.6.x throws a similar error with CoffeeScript 1.1.x; upgrading to 1.3.x does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Likely 2 different coffee-scripts on your system. check which coffee, than track down the older one and ice it. I had one from an install last summer (v1.1), it's all cleared up now.